# unknown option "-L3000:localhost:3000" while deploying Grafana

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, grafana, ssh-tunnel

I was following the single node file server [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs/single-node-fileserver?hl=en_US&authuser=3) on Google cloud platform where it told me to create an SSH tunnel, use the following gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag=-L3000:localhost:3000 --project=PROJECT --zone=ZONE INSTANCE_NAME
```

I enter the command on the gcloud sdk, and then I get this message.

> unknown option "-L3000:localhost:3000"

[Image of the message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krb0D.png)

What did I do wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `--ssh-flag="-L 3000:localhost:3000"`, PuTTY expects a space between the `-L` flag and the port definition.